Principal argument of $z^n$
I understand the process of finding the principal argument of a complex number if it has been raised to the power of n, i.e., $z^n$.
If we simply had z = x + iy then our principal value is defined to be in the range of $-\pi$ < $\theta$ < $\pi$. If we have $z^n$ though our principal value changes to $-n\pi$ < n$\theta$ < n$\pi$ and typically our value would land in this range.
Take the complex number, $z^5$ = $(1 + i)^5$. Our Arg (z) becomes $-5\pi$ < 5$\theta$ < 5$\pi$.
Can someone kindly explain what it is I am missing? The only thing I can think of is that we define Arg (z) to be $-\pi$ < $\theta$ < $\pi$ regardless of what z is raised to and so we do not change it but I need convincing.

If an example helps with MWP's +1 answer, think of $z = i$, whose principal argument is $\pi/2$. We have $i^5=i$ as complex numbers, so they have the same principal argument, i.e., $\operatorname{Arg} i^5 = \pi/2$, not $5\pi/2$.

Does this mean we should interpret it as an equivalence and not an equality?

I'm not sure what "it" is (the principal argument? the fact that $i^5 = i$? something else?), but suspect the answer is "no." The principal argument is a single-valued function on the non-zero complex numbers. The equation "$\operatorname{Arg}(z^n) = n\operatorname{Arg} z$" is not an identity, but holds if and only if $-\pi/n < \operatorname{Arg} z \leq \pi/n$. <> Incidentally, the same restriction holds for $\operatorname{Log}$, whose imaginary part is $\operatorname{Arg}$. Over-reliance on algebraic formalism is treacherous.

Your last sentence is pretty much correct. Just shift the "new" argument by an appropriate integral multiple of $2\pi$ so that the result is in the principal range.
You want a value of $n$ so that
$$-\pi < 5\theta -2n\pi\leq \pi$$
$$5\theta - \pi \leq 2n\pi < 5\theta + \pi$$
$$\frac{5\theta - \pi}{2\pi} \leq n < \frac{5\theta + \pi}{2\pi}$$
$$\frac{5\theta - \pi}{2\pi} \leq n < \frac{5\theta - \pi + 2\pi}{2\pi}$$
$$\frac{5\theta - \pi}{2\pi} \leq n < \frac{5\theta - \pi}{2\pi} + 1$$
This says you want the unique integer $n$ that lies in the interval $[w,w+1)$, where $w = \dfrac{5\theta - \pi}{2\pi}$.
Choosing that $n$, the principal argument is $5\theta - 2\pi n$ since it lies in $(-\pi,\pi]$.

Thank you for your reply. So the reason why we leave our argument between pi and -pi is a matter of convention? If yes, does this mean in some cases convention takes precedence over the algebra we’d typically apply?

Nothing wrong with using $5\theta$ here. The issue is that every nonzero $w$ has many arguments, differing by an integer multiple of $2\pi$. If $t$ is an argument, then all possible arguments are $$\ldots, t-4\pi, t-2\pi, t, t+2\pi, t+4\pi, t+6\pi\ldots$$ But there is exactly ONE of these that falls in whatever interval you choose to use for the values of the principal argument. Typically that is $(-\pi,\pi]$, but things like $[0,2\pi)$ are not uncommon. In fact, you can use any set that covers all possible angles exactly once, it doesn't even need to be an interval (rarely used).
